# Push and pull with Parse

Tags: parse-platform

So what I need is a kind of a push and pull web service mechanism; Certain devices will be sending data to my parse backend and some others should be able to receive the newly added data as it's being added. Think of it as a restaurant environment where customers send their order via their phones and the restaurant manager receives the orders on his pc real time.

I know I can use push notifications but I want to target specific users (in this case the manager alone). I guess I can have a specific push notification channel in which only the manager is added, but I am not sure if I can send proper json data in bulk or just simple strings. Maybe there's a smarter way of going about it.

Any suggestions?

Many thanks,
Polis

Comment: A push needn't contain any information except the awareness that there's something new on the server to be pulled.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Parse Cloud for this purposes. So certain devices (you can differentiate in cloud or in client side) can call the cloud method. The called cloud method can make http request to your server (manager pc  real time). From now on your server side can deliver coming message to your manager in real time. In this solution, I assume that you have your own server for web users (like manager) and mobile application for client user (customers).

Hope this can give you an idea. Regards.

Comment: It does actually, thanks. What if I just add an afterSave cloud trigger so that every time a new object of type Order is saved, the order is pushed to the manager?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Push notification for this purpose. In my opinion that would be your best option.

When registering for push notification on client side, you can set a column `owner` to user pointer. Now when sending push notification from one user to another you can query the `Installation` class for other user's pointer. You can send push notification either from client side or writing cloud code for `afterSave` trigger. Cloud code is a better option.

The downside of this approach is that if other user did not allow push notifications then this would fail. The second user would still be able to get the data when they open the app, but won't get push notifications.

***I built a chat app using this approach on Parse.com

Comment: So to make sure all customer orders are being pushed to the manager, I can define all customers as "owners" and the manager as "installation"?

Comment: No. ```owner``` will be just another column name in ```Installation``` class on Parse which will hold a pointer to ```User``` object. ```owner``` means the owner of the ```Installation``` row in Parse. I am assuming both customers and managers are of ```User``` class in Parse. If so, ```owner``` would be both customer and manager in installation class.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a complicated channel setup, before you save your installation, do a line like this:

```
[installation setObject:[PFUser currentUser] forKey:@"owner"];
[installation saveInBackground]; // ... completion or whatever
```

Then, just query:

```
PFQuery *installationQuery = [PFInstallation query];
[installationQuery whereKey:@"owner" equal:userImLookingFor];
```

Then, it's like `PFPush` w/ query or something.

(I'm typing from memory, so some of these might need to be slightly tweaked)

Comment: This looks good but I am wondering if it will work assuming the manager uses a PC and not a mobile device?

Comment: @Polis I've never setup push on OS X. This is iOS mobile code.